# How to cite a book in LaTeX using TexShop?

Tags: bibtex, citing, texshop

I am new to Latex and trying to cite a book in Latex. Using the previous answers here, I built a `.bib` file and saved it in the same directory. The file has been saved as bibDesk.I am trying to cite the book but nothing appears in the PDF. I did typeset several times but in no vain. The code, where I define IEEE referencing and the bibliography is:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[a4paper, margin=0.5in, footskip = 0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titling}

\date{}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetran}
\bibliography{References}
\end{document}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did you run the normal cycle: `(pdf)latex -> bibtex_>(pdf)latex (twice)`? If you use `biblatex, you might want to use `biber` rather than `bibtex`.

Comment: Thank you! I am confused about running BibTeX. Is it run by changing the typeset setting to BibTeX in the pdf latex file document?

Comment: Normally, it's a problem with your editor. Which do you use?

Comment: I am using TeXShop.

Comment: Idon't use it (I don't have Mac) but as far as I know, in TeXshop menus, you have a bibtex item you you just have to click on. The first run of (pdf)latex produces an auxiliary file that bibtex  uses to produce a .bbl file, used by (pdf)latex in the following runs to add the (formatted) bibliography to the .pdf and the citation commands.

Comment: Yes you can  use command-B to run bibtex. Or use the pdflatexmk engine to do it automatically.

Comment: I am getting this error now- This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2019)
The top-level auxiliary file: Progrees_report.aux
I couldn't open style file ieeetran.bst
---line 4 of file Progrees_report.aux
 : \bibstyle{ieeetran
 :                   }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no style file---while reading file Progrees_report.aux
(There were 2 error messages)

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I figured it out. I was writing IEEEtran and ieeetran and I think because Latex is case sensitive, it was not liking this much.

Comment: Note that from the example posted here you will not get any bibliography output, since you didn't cite anything. BibTeX will only add cited references to the bibliography. If you want to add a reference to the bibliography without `\cite`ing is explicitly use `\nocite{<key>}`. If you want to add all entries from your `.bib` file, use `\nocite{*}`.

Comment: That should be Shft-Cmd-B to run BibTex in TeXShop.